# Threshold comparison 2 different sized numpy arrays error

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I have been trying to get an evaluation of True when comparing these 2 different but similar numpy arrays. They are images that I isolated the trail from the rest of the map, I'm trying to get it to recognize (within a certain threshold) that it is the same path intersection. From my research I thought that np.allclose() would  be the way to go but I keep getting

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (477,1920) (588,1920)
I've tried np.testing_assert_almost_equal() but I get similar errors.

Is np.allclose() the right direction im just doing it wrong, or is there a better function for what I'm trying to do.

Attached is a picture of the 2 numpy arrays text files side by side. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
import numpy as np

# I have a numpy array that has isolated an intersection in a trial map/path 
from an image,
# I'm trying to get it to recognise the intersection (to a certain degree as 
it approaches) so
# I have a second numpy array that represents the trail map/path slightly 
before you are actually to
# the point where the intersection is.  So the 2 numpy arrays are different 
sizes because the second one
# has the intersection slightly higher up in the image because you just 
havent reached that point yet. But the
# arrays are still pretty similar. So I would want it to return True that 
they are almost the same Array and
# so I figured using np.allclose() with a threshold would work just fine. 
However
# I keep getting "ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with 
shapes (477,1920) (588,1920)".  When I try np.allclose()
```

[image]

```
def main():

    # Intersection array I am looking for
    intersectArray = np.loadtxt('Intersection.txt', dtype=int)

    # an array just before I've reached the same point at the intersection
    intersectArrayApproach = np.loadtxt('IntersectionApproach.txt', 
    dtype=int)

    print(np.allclose(intersectArray, intersectArrayApproach, .5, 
     equal_nan=True))

main()
```

Comment: Your arrays are not the same shape, you cant compare them.

Comment: @Dinari Of course you can compare them, just not as two full matrices. It is e.g. possible (with some type of metric) to find the smaller in the bigger. However, not in a simple fashion and not by using `np.allclose()` or `np.testing_assert_almost_equal()` as the OP wants.

Comment: Well with a custom metric you can compare any 2 objects :) I was referring to the fact you cant use the current OP logic to compare the 2 arrays.

Comment: Thank you, so there is no function is what you are saying? I had have to write a series of loops to check them?

Comment: You need some kind of image alignment to do what you want. I'd recommend googling for "python image alignment" or "cv2 image alignment"

Comment: @tel while I was looking over that, I was curious. If I just checked to see if the center of the image contained n array that was 8 elements tall that all were 255 all the way across, is that possible? that wouldn't isolate necessarily this exact intersection but it would identify that an intersection of some kind was present correct? how could I isolate say an [8,200] array from the input an compare it to see if it contains all 255 values... if not I would know that there wasn't an intersection at all.